# Cannot remove plugin's meta box from edit.php

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm trying to remove the plugin's [Page Links To](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/) metabox for Author user roles from the `edit.php` screen (article editing)... I can do it for all other metaboxes but `page-links-to`.

This is my code

```
if ( current_user_can('author') )
{

    function my_remove_meta_boxes()
    {
        remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', 'post', 'normal');
        remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv', 'post', 'normal');
        remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'post', 'normal');
        remove_meta_box('revisionsdiv', 'post', 'normal');
        remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post', 'normal');
        remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'post', 'normal');
        remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'post', 'normal');
        remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', 'post', 'side');
        remove_meta_box('categorydiv', 'post', 'side');
        remove_meta_box('postimagediv', 'post', 'side');

        remove_meta_box('page-links-to', 'post', 'normal');

    }
    add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

In plugin's source code I found this:

```
function do_meta_boxes( $page, $context ) {
        // Plugins that use custom post types can use this filter to hide the PLT UI in their post type.
        $plt_post_types = apply_filters( 'page-links-to-post-types', array_keys( get_post_types( array('show_ui' => true ) ) ) );

        if ( in_array( $page, $plt_post_types ) && 'advanced' === $context )
            add_meta_box( 'page-links-to', 'Page Links To', array( $this, 'meta_box' ), $page, 'advanced', 'low' );
    }
```

But I cannot find any way to detect a working hook to remove the metabox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options.

#### Add a lower priority to the hook.

```
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'my_remove_meta_boxes', 9999 );
```

By this point, the plugin hook should already have run and the removal will work. I suggest moving `current_user_can` inside the callback function `my_remove_meta_boxes()`.

#### Use the hook provided by the plugin

```
add_filter( 'page-links-to-post-types', 'remove_box_so_16290352' );

function remove_box_so_16290352( $post_types )
{
    $key = array_search( 'page', $post_types );
    if( $key !== false ) {
        unset($post_types[$key]);
    }

    return $post_types;
}
```

Comment: @NelloOllen, tested and updated the second option, it's working now :)

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615). I installed the plugin Page Links To and tested the code above with it, worked for me.

Comment: I was having trouble removing a meta box created by a plugin using the `admin_menu` action that WordPress suggests, but the `do_meta_boxes` action worked perfect. I didn't need to use a lower priority.